# Pre-fill database table column field with HTML using Laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I have added a new column to a database table using Laravel migration as follows:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddFAQToStoreTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('store', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->longText('FAQ')->after('description');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('store', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('FAQ');
        });
    }
}
```

As a default value for FAQ, I want the following HTML pre-filled for all stores when I run the migration:

```
<div><span style="font-weight:600">Can we get our purchase delivered?</span><br/>
Yes, items purchased can be delivered. However, due to COVID-19 restrictions, we are expecting a 3-5 business days' delay.</div>
```

Is it possible to add a new column and simultaneously pre-populate it with a HTML block like above? If it's better practice to use database seeders, please advise as well. Thanks

Comment: why not using the php side?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend don't use this method, store a simple paragraph in your DB and add it to your blade template with the desired tag but If you insist and want to insert default data such as `FAQ` or other things, which don't have a specific structure, you should add them with Laravel Query Builder like below:

```
// define table

   public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('store', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->longText('FAQ')->after('description');
        });
    }


// insert some stuff

    DB::table('store')->where('FAQ', '=', '')->update(array('FAQ' => '<div> . . . </div>'));
```

And use it in your blade template.

Comment: Thanks! I had to tweak your suggestion slightly to make it work for me. Instead of doing 'insert', I had to perform 'update', so it looks like the following now -

DB::table('store')->where('FAQ', '=', '')->update(array('FAQ' => '<div> . . . </div>'));

Comment: oh, nice... Thank you for letting me know. I updated my answer based on your experience so others can use it!

Answer (score 0):

You can update new column using Seeder and executing query.
1.Seeder - [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding)
2. executing query in your migration file

```
 public function up()
    {
         Schema::table('store', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->longText('FAQ')->after('description');
         });
         $html = '<div><span style="font-weight:600">Can we get our purchase delivered?</span><br/>
Yes, items purchased can be delivered. However, due to COVID-19 restrictions, we are expecting a 3-5 business days' delay.</div>';
         DB::statement('UPDATE store SET FAQ='.$html);
    }
```